# триггеры, не работает при вставке данных

Tags: sql-server

Здравствуйте! Я изучаю тему триггеры. Из разных источников я попытался собрать синтаксис

```
--создание триггера
CREATE TRIGGER имя_триггера ON имя_таблицы
FOR UPDATE | INSERT | DELETE
AS
BEGIN
 --инструкции
END
GO

--модификация триггера
ALTER TRIGGER имя_триггера ON имя_таблицы
FOR([UPDATE | INSERT | DELETE])
AS
BEGIN
 --инструкции
END
GO

--удаление триггера
DROP TRIGGER имя_триггера

--отключение триггера
DISABLE TRIGGER имя_триггера ON имя_таблицы

--включение триггера
ENABLE TRIGGER имя_триггера ON имя_таблицы
```

Вот решил сделать простой пример, который оказался для меня не простым. При вставке данных в таблицу, триггер должен автоматически записывать в поле DateInsert. До вставки данных, никаких ошибок. При вставке данных ошибки. Ошибка описана в примере. Подскажите, где и что я сделал не так. Зараннее спасибо.

```
--создание базы
CREATE DATABASE zzz
GO
--выбор базы
USE zzz
GO

--создание таблицы
CREATE TABLE Book (
 IDBook INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
 Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 Amount INT NOT NULL,
 Price MONEY NOT NULL,
 --это поле должен автоматически заполнять триггер
 DateInsert DATETIME NULL
)
GO

--создание триггера
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger ON Book
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
 /*при вставке данных, автоматически должно
 заполняться поле DateInsert*/ 
 INSERT INTO Book(DateInsert) VALUES 
 (CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME))
END
GO

/*
до вставки данных все выполняется без ошибок
*/
--вставка данных
INSERT INTO Book(Name, Amount, Price) VALUES
(N'Азбука', 10, 10.15)

--ошибка
/*
Не удалось вставить значение NULL в столбец "Name", таблицы "zzz.dbo.Book"; в столбце запрещены значения NULL.Ошибка в INSERT.
Выполнение данной инструкции было прервано.
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых, вам нужен `INSTEAD OF` триггер - ваш триггер просто вставляет еще одну строку, не отменяя оригинальную вставку.

Во вторых - вы должны перечилить все колонки - вы же заменяете оригинальный `INSERT`, а не просто добавляете в него значения:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger ON Book
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
 /*при вставке данных, автоматически должно
 заполняться поле DateInsert*/ 
 INSERT INTO Book(Name, Amount, Price, DateInsert) 
    SELECT Name, Amount, Price, (CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME))
    FROM inserted
END
GO
```

Comment: Огромное ВАМ спасибо!